# Eliminating Extra data from SQL

Tags: sql

So I have an SQL database with a table that has a column named City:

Some of the cities named are like so:

```
Houston, TX
San Francisco, CA
```

I want to eliminate the column and the state abreviation from the cities so that they are listed like this:

```
Houston
San Francisco
```

Is there an SQL command that can accomplish this?

Comment: what kind of DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MySQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('San Francisco, CA', ',', 1)
```

Replace `San Francisco, CA` with your column name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
SELECT LEFT('San Francisco, CA', CHARINDEX(',', 'San Francisco, CA')-1)
```

Replace `San Francisco, CA` with your column name.